# Notepad++ regex replace

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

id like to replace all the random numerical values to a solid value of a code
random values
ex:

```
DELAY : 214
DELAY : 1243
```

and id like to replace all them to

```
DELAY : 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are the settings I'd use:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One possability is

Search for   -->  DELAY : [0-9]*
Replace with -->  DELAY : 1